# Radio Buttons with changing button at the button(link) depending on option picked -- In Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

For the last few days I've been trying to make this relatively simple radio button -- similarly to this https://donate.unhcr.org/gb-en/general/ -- At the end of their page where they choose which amount they want to donate. I'm doing a bit of work for some charity and they'd like to have a similar form.

Through many hours of googling and trying out plug-ins and many more hours of trying to code it myself I've ended up in a very frustrating place with this.

**Could anyone point me in the right direction please, as to what to learn exactly or search for exactly?**

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly do you want to change when the buttons are clicked? Is it making the label and font bigger, or changing the image above, or both?

Comment: Hi, I'd like to change just the bottom link 'Make a monthly donation' button that I want to lead to different pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of jquery would achieve this. If you wanted it to change the link to the button at the bottom you could have a setup like this:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="1" /> Option 1</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="2" /> Option 2</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="option" value="3" /> Option 3</label><br />

<a id="mylink" href="/defaultpage">This link will go to <span>/defaultpage</span></a>

<script>
$('label').on('click', function() {

  var thisval = $(this).find('input').val();
  var newhref = '/defaultpage';

  if (thisval == 1) {
        newhref = '/mypage1';
  } else if (thisval == 2) {
        newhref = '/mypage2';
  } else if (thisval == 3) {
        newhref = '/mypage3';
  }

  $('#mylink').attr('href', newhref);
  $('#mylink').find('span').html(newhref);

});
</script>
```

For this you would have to include JQuery on your site, but I think Wordpress includes it by default.
Have a look at my jsfiddle to see it working:
https://jsfiddle.net/fLado8e5/

Comment: It is there by default but not under the `$` alias.

Comment: This has been exactly what I needed. With the help of a bit of tweaking It works just great. One question that I have is that I want to add CSS code to each individual label (like a bit of margin/padding/align) is there a way to do that or am I stuck to adding CSS to all of it as a whole block?

Comment: You can split the html up and style the bits separately, like this: `<label for="inputname">My Label</label> <input type="radio" id="inputname" />`. You could even wrap the whole thing in a div to give it some more styling.

Comment: PS I've updated the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fLado8e5/1/ to demonstrate. Can I get a green tick? Ta!

Comment: Thank you, what is a 'green tick'? Also, the new version needs to be clicked on the 'option' text rather than 'ticked' to show the right link at the bottom :( otherwise it does make sense. Will try to fix it though.

Comment: Next to the top of my answer, there is an up arrow and a down arrow. Below this, is a tick (or 'check' ). If you click this is means you accepted my answer!

Comment: Hi, I've ticked it as answer as it was the answer I needed for my original reply/problem --

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses PHP, so here is an example of radio button with html and php

`$gender = "";
<input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male`

The styling is done with toggling css classes.  Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! -- It almost solves it, the problem that I'm having is that I can't seem to figure out how to write the code that tells it to Redirect when clicked/selected

Comment: By redirect, you mean to change it's css classes?

Comment: I mean leading the visitor to a different address/webpage in the same website

Comment: You can use   `header("Location: http://www.yourwebsite.com/user.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();`   Exit stops code underneath it from executing